# Laravel 4.2: How to convert raw query to Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a raw query which works fine.

```
$qry ="select date(created_at) as Date,count(id) as Value from performances where date_format(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y') >= '$start_date' and date_format(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y') <= '$to_date' group by Date order by Date desc ";
    $stats = DB::select( DB::raw($qry) );
    return json_encode($stats);
```

I would like to convert it in to Eloquent

My controller function is

```
public function postPerformanceDetails()
{
$start_date = Input::get('start_date');
$to_date = Input::get('to_date');
$start_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($start_date));
$to_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($to_date));
$stats = Performance::where('created_at', '>=', $start_date)
        ->where('created_at','<=',$to_date)
        ->groupBy('perf_date')
        ->orderBy('perf_date', 'DESC')
        ->remember(60)
        ->get([
        DB::raw('Date(created_at) as perf_date'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(id) as perf_count')
        ])
        ->toJSON();
return $stats
}
```

The raw query works fine but eloquent does not work according to the date input.

I input data in this format 09-03-2015
in database the format is 2015-03-09

If we give 2015-03-09 as start_date and to_date it returns empty string.

Is there any problem with formats?
How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to convert the date in `PHP` to the database format.

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date));
```

This should lead to your database format: `2015-03-09`.

Comment: I have done as you suggested it partially ok.
But if we give 2015-03-09 start and to_date it returns empty string. @sleepless

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you. Can you explain it more precise?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English @sleepless.
If the input is 
$start_date = 2015-03-09 and
$to_date = 2015-03-09
the controller function returns empty string.

Comment: Do you mean the model returns null or the date / strtotime function?

Comment: I have edited the question `postPerformanceDetails()` function returns empty value If the input is $start_date = 2015-03-09 and $to_date = 2015-03-09 .

Comment: I just saw that it's created_at. So it's the field from laravel, right? Normally it is in this format:  2015-01-05 10:55:53. Isn't it? If so you need date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($start_date))

Comment: yes, correct Laravel. But I get only date (like 2015-03-09) from the view to variables $start_date and $to_date. I have tried `date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($start_date))` but result is same. If we give input minimum 1 day difference then it works fine, but, on same dates it fails.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is as follows: If you have a date like "2015-03-09 12:00:00" in your database your query can not work. You are then asking if it's over or equal (>=) 2015-03-09 00:00:00. This will return true. But then you ask if its ALSO under or equal 2015-03-09 00:00:00 which it isn't! If you want it to work you have to pass 2015-03-09 00:00:00 as start date and 2015-03-09 23:59:59 as end date. Only than it's in the range.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer as @sleepless suggested.

This is the code.

```
public function postPerformanceDetails()
{
    $event = Input::get('events');
    $start_date = Input::get('start_date');
    $to_date = Input::get('to_date');
    $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($start_date.'00:00:00'));
    $to_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($to_date.'23:59:59'));
    $stats = Performance::where('created_at', '>=', $start_date)
    ->where('created_at','<=',$to_date)
    ->groupBy('perf_date')
    ->orderBy('perf_date', 'DESC')
    ->remember(60)
    ->get([
    DB::raw('Date(created_at) as perf_date'),
    DB::raw('COUNT(id) as perf_count')
    ])
    ->toJSON();
    return $stats;
}
```